# Make KVM/libvirt wait for network mount before starting guests

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I'm managing an Ubuntu 16.04-based VM (running KVM/libvirt). The server hosts a few VMs that are used internally in our department.

All of the VMs use our company's Samba server for storing various bits and pieces of data.

During a power outage last night, I discovered that the machines boot much faster than the Samba server that they need, and which causes a bunch of services on the VMs to fail.

Rather than patch it on a VM-by-VM basis, I'd like to be able to just instruct my VM host to wait for the CIFS server before starting all of the VMs after reboot (basically, I'd like to make libvirt-guests.service depend on mnt-SHARENAME.mount).

I know that I could add a dependence in /lib/systemd/system/libvirt-guests.service, but I'm not sure if that's the systemd-approved method. Is there any other way to express the dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dummy "run once" service that sites between them.

In my case I have a problem with `xinetd` and `NFS` (xinetd starts before NFS filesystems have mounted so some of the services don't start).  I kludged this with a file `/lib/systemd/system/fix-xinetd-nfs-dependency.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Make xinetd wait for NFS otherwise it can not start services
After=remote-fs.target
Before=xinetd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once you've created your service (have the `Before` and `After` lines reflect your requirements) then you can `systemctl enable` it... and with luck this will run *before* your VMs have started and your samba filesystems available!

Comment: To make this work with `libvirt` I changed `xinetd.service` to `libvirt-guests.service` (and changed the comments and filename).